# Get string between two specific char positions

Tags: sas, scanf, extract, substr

i have a long text string in SAS, and a value is within it of variable length but is always proceeded by a '#' and then ends with ' ,'

is there a way i can extract this and store as a new variable please?

e.g:
word word, word, #12.34, word, word

And i want to get the 12.34

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Double scan should also work if you only have a single `#`:

```
data _null_;
  var1 = 'word word, word, #12.34, word, word';
  var2 = scan(scan(var1,2,'#'),1,',');
  put var2=;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `substr` and `index` functions to do this. The `index` function returns the first position of the character specified.

```
data _null_;
var1 = 'word word, word, #12.34, word, word';
pos1 = index(var1,'#'); *Get the position of the first # sign;
tmp = substr(var1,pos1+1); *Create a string that returns only characters after the # sign;
put tmp;
pos2 = index(tmp,','); *Get the position of the first "," in the tmp variable;
var2 = substr(tmp,1,pos2-1);
put var2;
run;
```

Note that this method only works if there is only one "#" in the string.

Comment: Thanks, this is great and works as a stand alone, but when trying to use it in my data step with a set statement it bring back everything after the '#'. Do i need to change the syntax for my data step?

Comment: Can you post what your data step looks like? The syntax is the same.

Comment: My apologies it does work!, thanks again. Just couldn't get the right combo of index, scan or substrings!

Comment: @J_Lard if you use FIND which has start column argument you could modify to search for multiple occurrences the target.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do is by using Regex and code is given below

```
data have;
infile datalines truncover ;
input var $200.;
datalines;
word word, word, #12.34, word, word
word1 #12.34, hello hi hello hi
word1 #970000 hello hi hello hi #970022, hi
word1 123,  hello hi hello hi #97.99
#99456, this is cool
 ;
```

A small note about below regular expression and functions

(?<=#) Zero-width positive look-behind assertion and looking for # before the pattern of interest

(\d+.?\d+) here means digit followed or not followed by . and other digits

(?=,) Zero-width positive look-ahead assertion and looking for , after the pattern of interest

call prxsubstr finds the position and length of pattern and substr extracts the required values.

```
 data want( drop=pattern position length);
 retain pattern;
 IF _N_ = 1 THEN PATTERN = PRXPARSE("/(?<=#)(\d+\.?\d+)(?=,)/");
 set have;
call prxsubstr(pattern, var, position, length);
if position then
  match = substr(var, position, length);    
 run;
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `index` to locate the two 'sentinels' delimiting the value and retrieve the innards with `substr`.  If the value is supposed to be numeric, an additional use of `input` function is needed.

A second way is to use a regular expression routines `prxmatch` and `prxposn` to locate and extract the embedded value.

```
data have;
  input; 
  longtext = _infile_;
datalines;
some thing #12.34, wicked
#, oops
#5a64, oops
# oops
oops ,
oops #
ok #1234,
who wants be a #1e6,aire
space #   , the final frontier
double #12, jeopardy #34, alex
run;

data want;
  set have;

  * locate with index;

  _p1 = index(longtext,'#');
  if _p1 then _p2 = index(substr(longtext,_p1),',');
  if _p2 > 2 then num_in_text = input (substr(longtext,_p1+1,_p2-2), ?? best.);

  * locate with regular expression;

  if _n_ = 1 then _rx = prxparse('/#(\d*\.?\d*)?,/'); retain _rx;
  if prxmatch(_rx,longtext) then do;
    call prxposn(_rx,1,_start,_length);
    if _length > 0 then num_in_text_2 = input (substr(longtext,_start, _length), ?? best.);
  end;

  * drop _: ;
run;
```

The **regex** way looks for ##.## variants, the index way looks only for **#...,**.  Then input function will decipher scientific notation values the regex (example pattern)way will not 'locate'.  The **??** option in the `input` function prevents invalid arguments NOTE:s  in the log when the enclosed value can not be parsed as a number.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to get really lazy you can just do

```
want = compress(have,".","kd");
```

Comment: This will not work as he is looking for number starting with # and  ending with ,